# Python read multiple .txt and plot in same figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have two .txt files of this form with thousands of rows

```html
episode:2840  score:6.0  memory length:700345  epsilon:0.5576491831247304   steps:359    recent reward:5.95
episode:2841  score:4.0  memory length:700629  epsilon:0.5574965123606621   steps:284    recent reward:5.96
episode:2842  score:5.0  memory length:700911  epsilon:0.5573449596383373   steps:282    recent reward:5.93
Max lifes :5
episode:2800  score:7.0  memory length:687331  epsilon:0.5646918805492361   steps:268    recent reward:6.04
episode:2801  score:5.0  memory length:687678  epsilon:0.5645029051613243   steps:347    recent reward:6.03
episode:2802  score:6.0  memory length:688027  epsilon:0.564312906709082   steps:349    recent reward:6.03
```

I want to plot how the `recent_reward` column, changes over the `episodes`. After I remove the `Max lifes :5` and some rows where the `episode` repeats, I get as a result two different plots, one for every file. However, the goal is to plot them together in one figure, to show the difference of the two `rewards` of the files over `episodes`. Could somebody help please?

This is my code :

```html
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob


# Read any .txt output file
path = '/home/plots/*.txt' 
files = glob.glob(path)


for name in files:
    # Read lines from file
    with open(name) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    # Extract episode/reward data points
    episodes = []
    rewards = []
    for line in lines:
        columns = line.split()
        if not columns[0].startswith("episode"):
            # Not a line with episode/reward data
            continue
        try:
            episode = int(columns[0].split(":")[1])
            reward = float(columns[7].split(":")[1])
        except:
            # Not a number
            continue
        if episode in episodes:
            # We don't want repeated episodes
            continue
        episodes.append(episode)
        rewards.append(reward)


    print(episodes,rewards)
    
    #plot both in the same figure
    #plt.plot(episodes, rewards, episodes, rewards)
    #plt.show()
    
    # Plot data every 1000 steps
    N = 1000
    for i in range(int(len(l_episodes)/N)+1):
        plt.plot(l_episodes[i*N:i*N+N], l_rewards[i*N:i*N+N])
        plt.xlabel('episodes', fontsize=12)
        plt.ylabel('rewards', fontsize=12)
        plt.savefig("plot{}.png".format(i))
        plt.close()
```

**Output figure**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating a list of lists and plotting them one by one? The solution below works for multiple files too.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob


# Read any .txt output file
path = '/home/plots/*.txt' 
files = glob.glob(path)

######################################################
# Create a list of episodes and reward from all files
l_episodes = []
l_rewards = []
######################################################
for name in files:
    # Read lines from file
    with open(name) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    # Extract episode/reward data points
    episodes = []
    rewards = []
    for line in lines:
        columns = line.split()
        if not columns[0].startswith("episode"):
            # Not a line with episode/reward data
            continue
        try:
            episode = int(columns[0].split(":")[1])
            reward = float(columns[7].split(":")[1])
        except:
            # Not a number
            continue
        if episode in episodes:
            # We don't want repeated episodes
            continue
        episodes.append(episode)
        rewards.append(reward)

    print(episodes,rewards)
    #################################
    # Append to the lists
    l_episodes.append(episodes)
    l_rewards.append(rewards)
    #################################

###########################################    
#plot both in the same figure
for i in range(len(l_episodes)):
    plt.plot(l_episodes[i], l_rewards[i])
###########################################
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Because I have a lot of episodes and the difference is not clear overall, I would like to make one plot every 1000 episodes. I have updated my code with what I was doing and was working, but when I tried to incorporate with your solution but I get a `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`. Could you perhaps help me with that too?

Comment: Would you please provide more details on your error message?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/plots/plots.py", line 96, in <module> plt.plot(l_episodes[i*N:i*N+N], l_rewards[i*N:i*N+N]) plt.close()`

`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Comment: I do not think `plt.plot(l_episodes[iN:iN+N], l_rewards[iN:iN+N])` will work. You are giving lists directly to `plt.plot`. That's why I implement a `for` loop to plot one by one. For your purpose, you might need to 1) run this script multiple times after batching your files or 2) write an outer `for` loop and create a new blank plot in every iteration to do this more properly.

Comment: The implementation depends on what you exactly want. Do you want a single figure with several subfigures, and save as one file? Or do you want to one figure each episodes period saved as multiple files? I recommend you to google the **images** of "matplotlib multiple figures" and read through appropriate examples.

Comment: Oh ok sorry for not being clear. I actually want one figure that will show the two plots of the two txt files, but only for the episodes when these two plots overlap. I uploaded the figure so that you have a picture of what it looks like. The blue plot begins at step 14000 and ends at 15000, so i'd like to plot these two text files for only those steps when you see both plots. Kind of "zooming in"

Comment: Then this has nothing to do with plotting. Adding an `if` statement before `episodes.append(episode)` and `rewards.append(reward)` to decide which data should be kept.

Comment: You are welcome. One final note: it usually will be beneficial to take a macroscopic view on what need to be plotted. Afterwards, plotting may be less confusing.